# Enum values in entity model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an enum for the days of the week:

```
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday
}
```

I'm trying to store an array or list of selected DaysOfWeek in an entity model that is used to persist data in a database using EF code first:

```
public IEnumerable<DaysOfWeek> SelectedWeekendDays { get; set; }
```

which should hold one *or more* DaysOfWeek values, but this yields a null value when populated as:

```
SelectedWeekendDays = new List<DaysOfWeek> { DaysOfWeek.Sunday, DaysOfWeek.Saturday }
```

So my question is, how can selected enum values be stored in an entity model. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `SelectedWeekendDays` used to persist data into the database? Can you also share how is your model used (EF code first or database first etc.)?

Comment: Alexei: thanks - updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that property is in your ViewModel,you can go with this approach: in your `POCO` class create a property like below and store the selected enum in there:

```
public DaysOfWeek SelectedEnum { get; set; }
```

Or if you want you can only store its numeric value

```
public int SelectedEnum { get; set; }
```

**Update**

For Multiple, you can create a int[] instead, so basically:

```
public int[] SelectedEnum { get; set; }
```

And Here how to populate it:

```
public int[] Population()
{
   int[] Example = { Convert.ToInt32(DaysOfWeek.Sunday), 
   Convert.ToInt32(DaysOfWeek.Saturday), so on... };
   return Example; 
}
```

Comment: Valkyriee: thanks for the suggestion, but I'm trying to store one or more values. I've tried int[] SelectedEnum but no dice - still a null value

Comment: @RickLiguz if you want to hold more than one item your approach is right, maybe you are populating it incorrectly?

Comment: .... many hours later ... your solution works for dynamic processing no problem, but I was hoping to store and retrieve the array to and from a db - in which case the solution doesn't work because (as far as I can make out) you can't store an array like this into a db - which is my bad for trying. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct you should define it [Flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute

```
[Flags]
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    None = 0,
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64
}
```

> Define enumeration constants in powers of two, that is, 1, 2, 4, 8, and so on. This means the individual flags in combined enumeration constants do not overlap.

And use [`Enum.HasFlag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx) to check enums selected

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I haven't come across the [Flags] attribute before so that's one for the improvements list. The main problem I had was (I think) down to trying to save the enum list to a database and retrieve it for processing, which doesn't work and isn't the way to go. Thanks again